# I haven't been able to discover how to make a button submit a FORM ~ and ALSO, work as an <a> LINK

Tags: php, html

I have scoured W3Schools, HTMLGoodies, Tizag and a dozen or 15 other ... sites; nothing really addresses this.  The closest discussion I found is the Question "How best to make a link submit a form" right here on StackOverflow, but that is a little past my grasp at the moment.

Just figured with PHP and HTML, the job would be doable.  Have things advanced in the last 3 years or is it still a matter of using JavaScript or some other language, and having to get into the DOM to make it all work?

Really hate to have to use one button to get the user to the spot on the page needed, then have to click a second button to open the div with the content displaying in it.  Much rather they be able to click a button  **View Comments** and the page goes to the  and the content is visible.

The last 2 times I have asked a question in here, were good; one in particular I was very grateful for.  Cheers! and if anyone has an answer I'd sure appreciate their help.

I could post 100 or so lines of code; a little demo, but will hold off on that.  Also, didn't wish to write out the half dozen or more things I tried which were ineffectual. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); $MeToo = mysql_connect('localhost','root','GuessHarder'); ?>
<?php if (!$MeToo) {die ('What ~ ARE you a Novice? !!! ? : ' . mysql_error());} ?>
<?php $InestimableUtility=99; ?>
<html><Head><Title>YESH Link VIEWER</Title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 06 charset=iso-8859-1 application/pdf  text/plain text/css text/php ">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YESH Tha CSS.css"/><br />
<?php 
// 3 sets of catching POSTS and setting some Vars.
$LINKfetched1=$_POST["1"]; 
$SleightOfHandx1= substr('\$LINKfetched1 ', 13);
$LinkzFaithfulListener1=$_POST["NICExExplosions1"];
$NICExExplosions1=99;
$LINKfetched2=$_POST["2"]; 
$SleightOfHandx2= substr('\$LINKfetched2 ', 13);
$LinkzFaithfulListener2=$_POST["NICExExplosions2"];
$NICExExplosions2=99;
$LINKfetched3=$_POST["3"]; 
$SleightOfHandx3= substr('\$LINKfetched3 ', 13);
$LinkzFaithfulListener3=$_POST["NICExExplosions3"];
$NICExExplosions3=99; ?> 
</Head>
<body id="Corpus">
<div id="LinkDisplayMAIN">
<div id="TopOfLinksContainDiv">
<div id="TitlePageLxDiv"><div id="LinkViewerTitleHerSELF">
The Links Viewer
</div><!-- LinkViewerTitleHerSELF --></div><!-- TitlePageLxDiv -->
</div><!-- TopOfLinksContainDiv -->
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><hr />
<pre>
<br /><br /><a name="LinkItemDisplayDiv1">Link 1</a><br /><br />
<div id="AutoGenLINKxDIV1"><br />
<div id="ParamsTOPforLink1"><br />
<div id="DbLINKdataboxy1"><div id="abcLinkNum1"><?php
echo '&nbsp'; ?>Link DB :    Link # <?php echo "1"; ?></div><!-- abcLinkNum1 --></div><!-- DbLINKdataboxy1 -->
<div id="AfterLinkNumSpacer1"></div>
</div><!-- from ParamsTOPforLink1 -->
<br /><br /><br />
<?php if($LinkzFaithfulListener1==99 and $InestimableUtility==99){ ?>
<div id="YeahBabyShowThoseNotes1">
<div id="lameDivText1">
<?php echo "In the grand scheme of things, accept that  um... you know, well."; ?><br />
</div><!-- lameDivText1 -->
</div><!-- YeahBabyShowThoseNotes1 --><?php } ?>
<div id="BottleFerButtonz1">
<div id="BttnOfLinkx1y1"><div id="Fake11">
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>"; method="post">
<input type="hidden"name="NICExExplosions1"value="<?php echo $NICExExplosions1; ?>"/>
<button type="submit">Show Notes About This Link</button></form>
<a href="#LinkItemDisplayDiv1">Goto Link 1</a>
</div><!-- from Fake11 --></div><!-- from BttnOfLinkx1y1 -->
</div><!-- from BottleFerButtonz1 --><br /><br /></div><!-- from AutoGenDBdtrmndDIV1 -->
</pre><hr /><br /><br /><br />

and a few more blocks, but that is the heart of the script;
```

and some closing tags.

```
    *** Following Day Edit by OP ***
```

So an example code block, cleaned up is simply:

```
<pre>
<a name="Anchored3"></a>
<div id="AutoGenLINKxDIV3">
<div id="ParamsTOPforLink3">
<div id="DbLINKdataboxy3"><div id="abcLinkNum3"><?php
echo'&nbsp'; ?>Link DB: Link #<?php echo "3";?></div></div></div>
<?php if($LinkzFaithfulListener3==99 and $InestimableUtility==99){?>
<div id="YeahBabyShowThoseNotes3">
<div id="lameDivText3">
<?php echo "$someVariableRepresentingTextorImageOrContentofsometype";?><br />
</div></div><?php }?>
<div id="BttnOfRelease3"><div id="FakeGetOuttaJail3">
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>#Anchored3"method="post">
<?php $PayloadMeNow3=$DaGoodez3; ?>
<input type="hidden"name="Liberte"value="<?php echo $Liberte; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden"name="EveryDangStepNeedsAVariable3"value="
   <?php echo $EveryDangStepNeedsAVariable3; ?>"/>
<button type="submit">Return To Link Viewing</button></form>
</div></div></pre>
```

Comment: it can be done with using a javascript function that runs when the anchor is clicked. use the javascript function to submit the form, and then redirect to the new link.

Comment: @ SenorAmor well, <button type="submit"><a href="#xyz"></a>View Comments</button> turns the button into a link, but the FORM doesn't get processed; and variants of that, all fail.  Placing the link inside the form; not so good.

Comment: @sberry and thank you as well.  Read the 2 or 3 pages of material there and will revisit it.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the question.  The only way to submit a form without leaving the page is to submit it with ajax.  So you would want to submit it via ajax, then call whatever you ware trying to do such as  open the div with the content displaying in it. see here http://www.simonerodriguez.com/ajax-form-submit-example/

```
<form name="MyForm" action="response_normal.php" method="post" onsubmit="xmlhttpPost('response_ajax.php', 'MyForm', 'MyResult', '<img src=\'pleasewait.gif\'>'); return false; YOURFUNCTIONHERE">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to send POST and GET vars you can do it by passing them in form action attribut like:

```
<form action="mypage.php?var1=1&var2=2&etc=n" method="post">
```

this will send your fields data with post method and pass GET vars in request too

Comment: Thanks, but since you answered, I added some code to the question.  It reinforces the key point that I want to POST and reposition/redirect via link, in a single button click.  $POSTing? no worries, many ways to do that.  Installing a link and having it work?  Well can have links all over the farm, either is okay, de nada.  If you have any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do redirection in your php script when will finish hendling data from form like:`header( "location:" . "mypage.php?var1=1&var2=2&etc=n" ); exit();`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript to do this. Here's a possible way to make it fallback as a normal link:

Since you are talking about comments, I think an example in terms of a blog would be most suitable. Assume that your body looks like this:

```
<body>
  <h1>My blog post!</h1>
  <p>My content</p>
  <a href="http://site.com/blog/my-blog-post/comments/">View Comments</a>
  <div id="comments></div>
</body>
```

Here's what you can do:

- If the user has javascript enable, use JQuery, YUI or your favorite JS library to send a request to `http://site.com/blog/my-blog-post/comments/`. Your server can detect if the request is AJAX, send back an HTML fragment containing the comments and then insert it into a `comments` div.
- If the user does not have Javascript enabled, the user will click the link to `http://site.com/blog/my-blog-post/comments/`. The server can identify that the `comments` flag is in the link, so it will render the whole page including the comments.

This way, you can have nice AJAX loading for javascript enabled users, and fallback for users without JS.

Comment: As I have it, the links will work to keep the page from loading and displaying at the start, at the top.  The precise effect I am striving for, is while the user is scrolling down the page, they see an item they wish to view more info about, click the *View* button and the script uses a link  name="foo" anchor to prevent the page going nuts and reloading at the top; AND of course, have a div open up to show the content.  It is so easy doing dynamic changes with php and html when a page is all in the viewport at once; this is an odd duck the insistence of the page to open at top.  Take care.

Answer (score 0):

The question was how to submit a form, and link to a particular place on the same page: with the caveat that it needed to be done with a single button click.  Not only stay on the same page, but more or less at the same place on the page; not find the page at the top after the click to view additional info.

My problem was that I had incorrectly thought that an Goto XYZ paired up
with the anchor Here: XYZ would be needed, and a lot of frustrating trying out various placements of those items, led me to worry I must need some other mechanisms to achieve the goal of submitting a form in order to control the opening of a div to show the user content and yet not have the page loading at the top.  Also relevant was the desire to permit the user to click a close button to hide the div once the content had been viewed, and again, not have the page open at the top.

The solution was to discover through a whole lot of trial and error, this simple bit of
syntax:

```
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>#Anchored3"method="post">
```

As long as this first component Anchor 3 is in place, the other statement,  does not need to be in the script and my experience was that it did harm most places I tried to situate it.  The anchor alone, is sufficient.
How drop~dead simple is that!

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar requirement and the only solution I found was to use the form to POST data to the same php file which does a database INSERT, process that post data AND THEN after that utilise curl to extract POST data modify/add more POST values and send it onto another php file like so to send an email;

```
    //send an email
        //extract data from the post
        $name = $_POST['fname']." ".$_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $web = "";
        $group_name = $_POST['group_name'];
        $message = "";
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $user_id = mysql_insert_id();
        //point to script
        $url = 'scripts/emailer.php';
        //set POST variables
        $fields = array(
                    'article_id'=>urlencode($article_id),
                    'name'=>urlencode($name),
                    'email'=>urlencode($email),
                    'web'=>urlencode($web),
                    'message'=>urlencode($message),
                    'username'=>urlencode($username),
                    'user_id'=>urlencode($user_id),
                    'group_name'=>urlencode($group_name),
                    'messagetype'=>'new_user'
                );

        //url-ify the data for the POST
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        rtrim($fields_string,'&');

        //open connection
        $email_post = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($email_post,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($email_post,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
        curl_setopt($email_post,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($email_post); //echo $result for testing

        //close connection
        curl_close($email_post);
    // end email approvers section
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a `<form>` by using the forms `action` parameter and `<input>` buttons `type` parameter as `submit` and also add an `<a>` link with attributes such as `href='#+your div id'` to get it on the same page after submitting the form.

Hope this helps you.